# Why does concrete class show references to other implementations of differently typed interface?

Tags: c#, interface, reference

I'm very new to C# and I'm working on a project, and I'm afraid that there is something about the way I'm going about this that is going to lead to trouble down the road.

I have a base generic interface:

```cs
public interface IApiService<TDto,TEntity>
       where TDto : IDto
       where TEntity : IEntity {
   public Task<TDto> GetOne(Guid id);
   public Task<IEnumerable<TDto>> GetMany();
   /* and so forth */
}
```

And then several typed interfaces that implement that:

```cs
public interface IUserService : IApiService<UserDto,User> {}
public interface IBuildingService : IApiService<BuildingDto,Building> {}
```

And then classes that implement the typed interfaces.

```cs
public class UserService : IUserService {
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _ctx;
    public UserService(ApplicationDbContext ctx){
        _ctx=ctx;
    }
    public async Task<UserDto> GetOne(Guid id){
        return await _ctx.Users.Where(c=>c.Id==id).SingleAsync();
    }
    // etc.
}

public class BuildingService: IBuildingService {
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _ctx;
    public BuildingService(ApplicationDbContext ctx){
        _ctx=ctx;
    }
    public async Task<BuildingDto> GetOne(Guid id){
        return await _ctx.BuildingDto.Where(c=>c.Id==id).SingleAsync();
    }
    // etc.
}
```

In Visual Studio, when I click on the little references link above the method `GetOne` in one of the classes, it shows me references to all implementations of `GetOne` even though they are all different types.  Using above as an example, it says `GetOne<Building>` is the same as `GetOne<User>`.  This seems to me like it will cause confusion / or that I did something wrong because those references are actually different methods and different interface implementations.

My question is, since my understanding is obviously lacking, how is it lacking?  Am I misunderstanding how to interpret references, and everything I've done is fine and won't cause problems?  Or am I misunderstanding something else, and if so, what, and what issues might be caused?

Comment: Visual Studio is showing _all_ implementations of the 'GetOne' method regardless of the generic type. I would say that's a limitation of the IDE, not a limitation of your code. Everything you've written is easy enough to follow.

Comment: You're fine. You haven't created a code issue. You're just being thrown by the UI which is including base types and derived types. In the 'Find References' window you can filter by reference type.

Comment: With the 'Show References' button, if the method you are looking at comes from an interface or a base class, Visual Studio will show all references to the base declaration as well as to the current implementation. That's quite useful, because when you use dependency injection you typically never refer to the concrete implementation directly, you always call it through an interface

Comment: Got it.  @AndrewWilliamson - I'd just think it would go directly to the scoped implementation of the interface (which in this case is the direct parent, i.e. IUserService) rather than also including sibling interfaces (i.e. IBuildingService) - edit - scratch that.  I understand what you are saying.  Because that's where the source methods will be.  Thanks.  That makes sense